# Laravel: assertDatabaseHas - unexpected fail

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I don't understand why this database test fails. I'm aware that i don't assert on the created_at and updated_at columns, but the three columns (id, user_id, thing_id) should be enough and i'm sure that i have tested on just a selection of columns before, and it has worked!

What am i missing?

```
    Failed asserting that a row in the table [thing_history] matches the attributes [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "user_id": 1,
                "thing_id": 1
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "user_id": 1,
                "thing_id": 2
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 1,
                "thing_id": 3
            }
        ].

        Found: [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "user_id": "1",
                "thing_id": "1",
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "user_id": "1",
                "thing_id": "2",
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17"
            },
            {
                "id": "3",
                "user_id": "1",
                "thing_id": "3",
                "created_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17",
                "updated_at": "2019-02-01 21:18:17"
            }
        ]



This is the test code

    /** @test */
    public function retrieving_feed_creates_history()
    {
        $user = factory('App\User')->create();

        $this->actingAs($user);

        factory('App\Thing', 3)->create();

        $response = $this->json('GET', '/api/thing/feed/all');

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('feed_histories', [
            [
                'id' => 1,
                'thing_id' => 1,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ],
            [
                'id' => 2,
                'thing_id' => 2,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ],
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'thing_id' => 3,
                'user_id' => $user->id,
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

This is the migration code:

```
  public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('feed_histories', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id');
                $table->integer('thing_id');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Comment: Can you add your test, and your migration table, thank you

Comment: Added the test code and the migration code.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like i have misunderstood something. To check several rows, i have to split the test into into separate assertions for each row.

This works fine:

```
$this->assertDatabaseHas('feed_histories', [
        'thing_id' => $thingA->id,
        'user_id' => $user->id, 
]);

$this->assertDatabaseHas('feed_histories', [
        'thing_id' => $thingB->id,
        'user_id' => $user->id, 
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, the map of multiple records fails as assertDatabaseHas function currently only handles a single row by mapping a single row in the where clause...

To get a better insight, you can have a look at the base function of assertDatabaseHas

```
public function matches($table): bool
{
    return $this->database->table($table)->where($this->data)->count() > 0;
}
```

here, the $this->data refers to the second argument of assertDatabaseHas funciton
So, it clears out our doubt of why we can't pass array of arrays.